# sqlite3_last_insert_rowid returns 0 after the first insert

Tags: ios, c, sqlite

I'm using the following code to insert a row into a database. For some reason, sqlite3_last_insert_rowid returns the correct row ID for the first row inserted, but after that it always returns 0.

Between inserts other DB actions may have occurred, like a deletion of a row.

_scoresDB is an instance var.

Here's my insert code:

```
-(void)insertScore:(OKScore*)score
{
    const char *dbpath = [[self dbPath] UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_scoresDB) == SQLITE_OK) {

        // Setup the SQL Statement
        if(insertScoreStatement == nil) {
            //OKLog(@"Preparing statement for cache score");
            const char *insertSQL = "INSERT INTO OKCACHE(leaderboardID,scoreValue,metadata,displayString,submitted) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);";

            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_scoresDB, insertSQL, -1, &insertScoreStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
                OKLog(@"Failed to prepare score insert statement with message: '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(_scoresDB));
                return;
            }
        }

        // Bind the score values to the statement
        sqlite3_bind_int(insertScoreStatement, 1, [score OKLeaderboardID]);
        sqlite3_bind_int64(insertScoreStatement, 2, [score scoreValue]);
        sqlite3_bind_int(insertScoreStatement, 3, [score metadata]);

        if([score displayString]) {
            sqlite3_bind_text(insertScoreStatement, 4, [[score displayString] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        } else {
            sqlite3_bind_null(insertScoreStatement, 4);
        }
        sqlite3_bind_int(insertScoreStatement, 5, (int)[score submitted]);

        //Execute the SQL statement
        if(sqlite3_step(insertScoreStatement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            int scoreID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(_scoresDB);
            [score setOKScoreID:scoreID];
            OKLog(@"Cached score : %@",score);
        } else {
            OKLog(@"Failed to store score in cache wihth error message: %s",sqlite3_errmsg(_scoresDB));
        }


        sqlite3_reset(insertScoreStatement);
        sqlite3_clear_bindings(insertScoreStatement);
        sqlite3_close(_scoresDB);

    } else {
        OKLog(@"Could not open cache DB insertScore");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot keep a statement for a database that is already closed.
If you try to reuse that old statement, nothing will be inserted (neither into the old database, because it's closed, nor into the new database, because the statement doesn't know about it).

Before closing the database, you *must* free the statement with [sqlite3_finalize](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be retaining your insertScoreStatement.  You have already bound values to it, now you are binding more stuff onto it.  I would make it a local variable (not a class one nor a property) like this:

```
    // Setup the SQL Statement
    sqlite3_stmt *insertScoreStatement
    //OKLog(@"Preparing statement for cache score");
    const char *insertSQL = "INSERT INTO OKCACHE(leaderboardID,scoreValue,metadata,displayString,submitted) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);";

   if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_scoresDB, insertSQL, -1, &insertScoreStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        OKLog(@"Failed to prepare score insert statement with message: '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(_scoresDB));
            return;
        }
    }
```